# gotoAndPlay after sound ends as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I would like my timeline to advance to a certain labeled frame after a sound completes.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
var n1Channel:SoundChannel = new narratorAlphabetSounds();
n1Channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, audioComplete);
function audioComplete(e:Event):void
{
gotoAndPlay("step2");  
}
```

The sound fails to load and errors occure when trying to test. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you put the errors that you'v got ?

Comment: Here is the error:  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type narratorAlphabetSounds to an unrelated type flash.media:SoundChannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the implicit coercion error because your `narratorAlphabetSounds` object is a [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) object and not a [`SoundChannel`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html) one .. then to play your sound and detect when it has finished playing, you should use a `Sound` and a `SoundChannel` objects, like this :

```
var sound:Sound = new narratorAlphabetSounds();

var sound_channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
    sound_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, audioComplete);

function audioComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    trace('audio complete');
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This answer was very helpful.  I understand now and have been able to successfully accomplish my goal with this code.  Thank you so much!